# Compare and Compile data from various Columns into 2 columns

Tags: excel

Im having some difficulties with getting excel to do what I want.

The situation im in:

Every week, i get a report of about 500 worker IDs with some values. These IDs and values does not come with the name of the worker. So what im trying to do, is to have Excel search for the IDs in another column and the return the worker name from 2 columns (first and lastname).

The layout:

A: Workers Name

B: Worker ID

D: List of IDs without name

E: list of values, that the worker has produced throughout the week.

Result should be something like:

If Worker ID from D exits in B, then it would take Worker name from A and the value from E into G and H.

G: Worker Name

H: Value from E matching the same ID from E.

Is this even possible? Since i havent been able to figure out a suitable solution, which would make my job a lot easier and make me able to use more time on actual work, than on getting excel to work as i want it to.

I have been looking at VLOOKUP, but havent been able to wrap my head around, how it would be possible to make it work.

Any help is appreciated.

[Layout of Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7EZS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

`Vlookup()` is a nice function, but you cannot return a value from column 1, by looking for data in column 2.  You want to use [`Index/Match`](http://eimagine.com/say-goodbye-to-vlookup-and-hello-to-index-match/).

A quick test: Say your ID you want to look up is in `X2`, and your columns are as outlined...try this `=Index($A:$A,match(X2,$C:$C,0))` which should return the First name for the user.

To get the second name, just combine two formulas together with a separator: `=Index($A:$A,match(X2,$C:$C,0))&", "&=Index($B:$B,match(X2,$C:$C,0))`

Edit: Hm, here's a screenshot to hopefully clarify if I understand your question, and you can see how the match should work:

[image]

So, as you drag that down, in `H4`, it looks for `m59908` from Column D, searches for it in column B, then returns the name from Column A of that row.

Comment: Hey bruce, ive updated the layout a bit, so that the name is in 1 column, instead of 2. Makes it a bit easier on the eyes :)

Comment: Oh okay - are you able to get the `Index/Match` working?

Comment: havent tried it yet, but with the recent update of the info, wouldnt that create an error?

Comment: @SørenAlbérChristensen - If you combined the names together into Column A, then just use the first example `=Index($A:$A,match(x2,$C:$C,0))` assuming your `X2` is an ID number, and `$C:$C` has your ID numbers, with the corresponding name in `$A:$A`.

Comment: Im getting an error saying that its not a correct formula. Im using Excel 2016. 

Im probably doing it wrong though. But im guessing that the index/match has to go into column G?

Comment: @SørenAlbérChristensen - What formula are you using? (Edit into your OP)

Comment: Im using the example that you wrote previously. 

=Index($A:$A,match(x2,$C:$C,0))

however its only highlighting A and not the rest of the cells.

Comment: @SørenAlbérChristensen - See my edit - do I understand your question? If not, can you see what you can do with index/match to get it?

Comment: Hej bruce, it dosnt seem to work as planned :( Not sure what im doing wrong.

http://i.imgur.com/9QTddOs.jpg

Comment: However Bruce, i need the ID in D and the Value in E to remain together. So if D exits in B, then D and E gets shown in H and I.

Comment: And then this went down the drain :) Did you give up on me, @Bruce ? :D

Comment: @SørenAlbérChristensen - What error do you get with the Index/Match formula? Also, check that the values in your column B are trimmed (don't have any extra spaces after the text, like `m5569 ` should be `m5569`)

Comment: if you look at my comment the 9th, you see a link for a screenshot i took. Thats the "error" im getting. It dosnt seem to work, when i type it exactly how you did, in your edit :)

Comment: @SørenAlbérChristensen - Sorry, not trying to be a pain! But the screenshot just shows the formula, not the error. What's the error? `#VALUE`, `#N/A`, etc?